# Can't update UIlabel text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

In my iPhone App I have `ViewController1` that contains a `UILabel` called `selectedBook` and I added to its view in the storyboard and I connected the outlets.

I have another view controller called `ViewController2` and I pass some data from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1` and the text of the `UILabel` is one of them.

In `ViewController1` I wrote the following code:

in ViewController1.h

```
@interface ViewController1 : UIViewController{

  IBOutlet UILabel *selectedBook;

  NSString *BookName;
  NSString *BookCover;
  NSString *BookAbout;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *BookName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *BookCover;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *BookAbout;

-(void) setTheSelectedBook:(NSString *)bookName bookCover:(NSString *)bookCover bookAbout:(NSString *)bookAbout userID:(int)userID;
```

In ViewController1.m

```
-(void) setTheSelectedBook:(NSString *)bookName bookCover:(NSString *)bookCover bookAbout:(NSString *)bookAbout userID:(int)userID
{
    BookName = bookName;
    BookCover = bookCover;
    BookAbout = bookAbout;

    NSLog(@"in setTheSelectedBook, BookName: %@ - BookCover: %@ - BookAbout: %@ - userID: %d", BookName, BookCover, BookAbout, userID);

    selectedBook.text = bookName;
}
```

In `viewController2` I wrote the following code:

```
ViewController1 *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Suggest"];
[viewController setTheSelectedBook:@"MybookName" bookCover:@"MyBookCover" bookAbout:@"MuBookAbout" userID:1];
```

My data pass properly and I see it in the output, but the problem is that the `UILabel` text is not updated, meaning that this line

```
selectedBook.text = bookName;
```

does not work.

I tried writing it as `selectedBook.text = @"someText";` and this works.

I can't understand what's missing to make `selectedBook.text = bookName;` work? I hope someone help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `setTheSelectedBook:bookCover:bookAbout:userID:`, you have a `NSLog` line. What does that output in the console in Xcode?

Comment: in setTheSelectedBook, BookName: MybookName - BookCover: MyBookCover - BookAbout: MuBookAbout - userID:1

Comment: It is the target output.

Comment: Does it work if you use `selectedBook.text = BookName;` (the variable with uppercase B)?

Comment: @neilco that's what I thought as well... But apparently that's not the case. Eman87 can you show the whole method in viewController2 where you set the label text?

Comment: No not work when I change to BookName. :(

Comment: @Eman87 Can you show us how BookName, BookCover, and BookAbout are defined? Are they properties? Are you using automatic synthesis?

Comment: I edited and added .h file of ViewController1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing. Never begin your variables with a capital letter. `BookName` should be `bookName` or `_bookName`. I think that's one of the problems.

If you instead create a Book-class with the variables:

```
@property (copy) NSString *name;
@property (copy) NSString *cover;
@property (copy) NSString *about;
```

Then in your `viewController1` create the book by instantiating your Book-class and set it's variables, you could then send your Book-object to your `viewController2`.

That would probably be easier for you.

**If you just want to change your own code, you could try with:**

In your h-file:

```
@property (copy) NSString *BookName;
@property (copy) NSString *BookCover;
@property (copy) NSString *BookAbout;
```

And in your m-file:

```
-(void) setTheSelectedBook:(NSString *)bookName bookCover:(NSString *)bookCover bookAbout:(NSString *)bookAbout userID:(int)userID
{
    _BookName = bookName;
    _BookCover = bookCover;
    _BookAbout = bookAbout;

    NSLog(@"in setTheSelectedBook, BookName: %@ - BookCover: %@ - BookAbout: %@ - userID: %d", BookName, BookCover, BookAbout, userID);

    selectedBook.text = _BookName;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll take your words in consideration. That's because that I'm new in programming. But do you this that the text in uilabel not updated because if the name of variables??

Comment: does it work if you change selectedBook.text = bookName; to selectedBook.text = BookName;

Comment: I can't really understand your code. Do you have "(void) setTheSelectedBook:(NSString *)bookName bookCover:(NSString *)bookCover bookAbout:(NSString *)bookAbout userID:(int)userID{" method in both viewController1 and in viewController2

Comment: I tried before to use (setNeedsDisplay) to pass data, the data passed properly and I got it, but the uilabel still not updated. it works when I add any string like this `selectedBook.text = @"someText";`

Comment: No I just call setTheSelectedBook in viewController2

Comment: Still get the properly output, but the label text not updated :( I think that the problem is not variables name. I think that the uilable miss something I don't know what it is

Comment: Put up a link to the code and I can have a look at it if you want.

Comment: Its not me.. Thanks so much for your help but I used an alternative way. and I got my target. But thank you for your efforts to help me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I see here is, that bookName is not an NSString.

Add the following line to that method:

```
NSLog(@"bookName class is %@", [bookName class]);
NSLog(@"selectedBook class is %@", [selectedBook class]);
```

What does XCode write to the log during runtime?